# How to automatically trigger releases in Azure Devops, from multiple branches, using multiple artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Say you have a build and its corresponding release definition on Azure Devops.

Generally, the way it's used is like:

Repository "A" changes -> Build repo "A" -> Release to a given environment

Within this scenario (using only one build artifact), it's easy to trigger deployments (after successful build) for different branches.

But, say you also have a release definition with multiple build artifacts (from different repos), and you want to, changes coming from branch "dev" you want to deploy to environment "Development", but if changes come from branch "hotfix" you want to deploy to environment "Staging".

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V42J9.png)

You can play with branch filters on the specific environment and artifact filters on the artifact triggers.

The above scenario works very well for "dev" changes when you define your build artifacts to use "dev" as default branch.

But if you make changes on Repo A (branch hotfix), but not in Repo B, the build artifacts for that release will come from different branches, hence the "artifacts will not meet requirements", cause all changes must come from hotfix branch in order to trigger the deployment.

In my opinion, the "Default Version" of the Build Artifact itself, makes this confusion for the pipeline.

[See this image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d43WX.png)

That being said, how can we trigger a deployment into "Staging" environment if only one of the triggered changes come from the branch "hotfix" ?

The way I can see, when that happens, "Staging" environment never "meets the artifacts requirements", cause other artifacts will use version from "dev" as it's the default source branch.

Has anyone worked with a similar scenario ?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

According to your scenario, the best solution at present is to create two release pipelines to deploy separately, because Artifact A and Artifact B have no dependencies.

In the Continuous deployment trigger of the build artifact, you can set Build branch filters to include the dev and hotfix branches.

[image]

Then enable `Artifact filters` in the Pre-deployment conditions of the stage to set the `build branch` artifact conditions that trigger the deployment.

**Artifact filters**: Select artifact condition(s) to trigger a new deployment. A release will be deployed to this stage only if all artifact conditions match.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and examples. I did the same as you suggested, but it turns out that we need to specify on the build artifacts itself, what is the default version (from which branch), and that's the issue with this azure pipeline, if we make changes on Repo A (branch hotfix), but not on Repo B (branch dev), the release will be created, but not triggered cause artifacts from Repo B will come from its default version "dev".
If I change default version to "hotfix" it might work, but then "dev" environment will not work.

Comment: Why set the default version to `Latest from a specific branch with tags`? You can choose `Latest` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F63g8.png), and then filter the build branch in `Continuous deployment trigger`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, I thought that would work as well, but unfortunately when doing this, there might scenarios where I make changes to Repo A (hotfix branch), but someone else already made changes to Repo B (but dev branch).
As a result, the latest version from Repo B will be from dev, hence, artifacts will continue to not meet requirements.

Comment: So far, the only way I could make this work, was creating separated release definitions, to attend specifically hotfix/staging environment.

Comment: Here agree with you , according to your scenario, the best solution at present is to create two release pipelines to deploy separately, because Artifact A and Artifact B have no dependencies and there is no need to consider filtering, trigger conditions etc when using two release pipelines.